# How to get the phone num leading with zero while exporting the data to excel ,csv,HTML

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i am using the below query

```
select ''||'001234567890'||'' from dual;
```

this will work for .xslx and HTML but csv its not working

is there any another way to show where for all three formats it will show correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"? And how are you "using" that query? How do you export the result to csv? The way you export to csv is almost surely where you are making the mistake; that has nothing to do with the query you use. As an aside - how do you even know that the exported data is wrong? How are you viewing it? Do you open it as plain text, or do you just open it in Excel, and if Excel doesn't show the leading zeros, you assume they aren't in the csv file?

Comment: Please, describe how this query is related to csv/xlsx/html. When the data gets extracted from the database, the question has nothing about the database. When the data is inside the database, it has nothing about csv/html/xml. The question is not clear.

Comment: @astentx if i am trying to export the data of my table directly from DB to csv format the amounts which are like 890.00 is showing like 890 only ,And Phn number which are begin with Zeros are trimming after exporting to csv directly no code is user here directly i am exporting

Comment: @shah Because Excel treats numbers as numbers when it opens csv directly. You may use "Import data -> From text" and specify format for each column or read CSV with Power Query and delete datatype conversion step.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, an empty string `''` is the same as `NULL` so your query:

```sql
select ''||'001234567890'||'' from dual;
```

Is the same as:

```sql
select NULL||'001234567890'||NULL from dual;
```

Which is the same as:

```sql
select '001234567890' from dual;
```

---

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/318420/formatting-a-comma-delimited-csv-to-force-excel-to-interpret-value-as-a-string), for a csv file that you are importing into Excel, you want the format `"=""001234567890"""` which would give the query:

```sql
select '"=""001234567890"""' from dual;
```

or, if you are concatenating strings:

```sql
select '"=""' || '001234567890' || '"""' from dual;
```

There will not be one single method that works for all 3 formats as, although HTML and Excel's .xlsx format are both XML derivatives (yes, HTML is not XML) and you can probably find something that works for both of those, CSV is a very different format.